# HTML5 placeholder css padding

Tags: html, google-chrome, webkit, css

I've seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css) already and tried everything I could to change the padding for my placeholder but alas, it seems it just doesn't want to cooperate.

Anyway, here is the code for the css. (**EDIT**: This is the generated css from sass)

```
#search {
  margin-top: 1px;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 220px;
}

#search form {
  position: relative;
}

#search input {
  padding: 0 10px 0 29px;
  color: #555555;
  border: none;
  background: url('/images/bg_searchbar.png?1296191141') no-repeat;
  width: 180px;
  height: 29px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#search input:hover {
  color: #00ccff;
  background-position: 0px -32px;
}
```

And here's the simple html:

```
<div id="search">
  <form>
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Search..." name="q" autocomplete="off" class="">
  </form>
  <div id="jquery-live-search" style="display: block; position: absolute; top: 15px; width: 219px;">
    <ul id="search-results" class="dropdown">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Pretty simple? the placeholder is off for some reason but when you try to type in the input field, the text is the aligned. It seems that you can only change the color(for `webkit`) of the placeholder, but if I try to edit the padding of the containing input, it wrecks the design of the input! *pulls out hair*

Here are screenies of the placeholder and the input field with text input:

[image: placeholder]
[image: text input]

**EDIT**:

For now I have resorted to this [jquery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-placeholder/).

It works right out of the box and it fixes my chrome's problem. I would still like to uncover what the problem is (if it has something to do with MY chrome or something)

I'm pretty sure it's not the styles since John Catterfeld reproduced it with no problems, so I'm hoping someone out there could still point me to the right direction as to why this is happening to me(my client's chrome as well. So this is probably native to Chrome/OSX if John is using windows)

Comment: Can you provide the generated CSS? That would be much easier to work with than the SASS source.

Comment: +1 That plugin is awesome - simple and has right the options i need. Probably best placeholder solution i stumble upon till now.

Comment: If anyone has a problem with bootstrap setting these two options help: font-size: large; instead of px; and line-height:normal;

Answer (score 238, accepted):

I got the same issue.

I fixed it by removing line-height from my input. Check if there is some lineheight which is causing the problem

Comment: Wrong. With an input element the placeholder is not effected by line-height, but padding is not the best solution. The best is to use (and I know it normally never does anything, but in this case it does) the VERTICAL-ALIGN CSS property.

Comment: Yes, surprisingly, that DID fix the issue. And the typed text still stays vertically centered even without the line-height help.

Comment: when there wasn't line-height on the input directly, then adding `line-height: normal;` did the trick for me

Comment: Anyway you have to add line-height for ie browsers, but that do the job for safari

Answer (score 173):

I had similar issue, my problem was with the side padding, and the solution was with, text-indent, I wasn't realize that text indent effect the placeholder side position.

```
input{
  text-indent: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 28):

If you want to keep your line-height and force the placeholder to have the same, you can directly edit the placeholder CSS since the newer browser versions. That did the trick for me:

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
input:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
input::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 25):

```
line-height: normal;
```

worked for me ;)

Comment: Works in Safari.

Comment: Worked in safari

Answer (score 6):

**Angular Material**

add `&nbsp;` in the `placeholder` if `padding` did not work - **but not a recommended way**

```
<input matInput type="text" placeholder="&nbsp;&nbsp;Email">
```

**Non Angular Material**

Add `padding` to your `input` field, like below. Click `Run Code Snippet` to see demo

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container m-3 d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-around" style="height:100px;">
<input type="text" class="pl-0" placeholder="Email with no Padding" style="width:240px;">
<input type="text" class="pl-3" placeholder="Email with 1 rem padding" style="width:240px;">
</div>
```

Comment: adding &nbps; is a very bad practice.

Comment: @CristianSepulveda you're right. It's just a work around when nothing else works.

Comment: you should tell that very explicit in your answer. the way it is redacted could seems like this way is a good practice.

Comment: Nah &nbsp; works fine, better than using 999999 lines of CSS to achieve something simple like this.

Answer (score 3):

I had a problem, which appears just in internet explorer. Input field was styled

```
height:38px;
line-height:38px;
```

Unfortunately in IE the initial placeholder appears not at the correct position. But when I have clicked into the field and then left this field, the placeholder appeared on the right position.

My solution was to set:

```
line-height:normal;
```

Answer (score 3):

Setting `line-height: 0px;` fixed it for me in Chrome

Comment: Can you explain what this adds to the accepted answer from four years ago?

Comment: @NathanTuggy to me the accepted answer suggested that you remove the `line-height` attribute entirely from the element. For me that did nothing, and what fixed the problem for me was to set `line-height: 0px`

Comment: Same here, this is what actually fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you want move placeholder text right and leave the cursor on the blank space you need to add space(s) at the start of the placeholder attribute:

```
<input type="email" placeholder="  Your email" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Removing the line-height indeed makes your text align with your placeholder-text, but it doesn't properly solve your problem since you need to adapt your design to this flaw (it's not a bug). Adding vertical-align won't do the deal either. I haven't tried in all browsers, but it doesn't work in Safari 5.1.4 for sure.

I have heard of a jQuery fix for this, that is not cross-browser placeholder support (jQuery.placeholder), but for styling placeholders, but I haven't found it yet.

In the meantime, you can resolve to [the table on this page](http://blog.ajcw.com/2011/02/styling-the-html5-placeholder/) which shows different browser support for different styles.

Edit: Found the plugin! [jquery.placeholder.min.js](http://www.mediafire.com/file/hyb94ktm7g60x09/placeholder.zip) provides you with both full styling capabilities and cross-browser support into the bargain.

Comment: was trying to find a non placeholder fix though as i already used the jquery plugin above :) thanks for the help!

Comment: Keep in mind though that these are two different plugins. I'm not sure what the one you're using does (the demo doesn't work in any of my browsers), but this one uses the placeholder attribute of the element, and dynamically creates a span rendered above the input field, which provides maximum styling possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Remove line-height  or set using padding...it's working in all browser

Answer (score 1):

I've created a fiddle using your screenshot as a background image and stripping out the extra mark-up, and it seems to work fine

http://jsfiddle.net/fLdQG/2/ (webkit browser required)

Does this work for you? If not, can you update the fiddle with your exact mark-up and CSS?

Comment: hmm i checked the link and it doesn't work for me as well. do you think there's a plugin/something in my chrome that's causing it? screenshot: http://grab.by/8OFf

Comment: checked it using safari and it works. shouldn't chrome and safari render the same thing?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not aware of a plugin that would affect your layout like this, but Chrome and Safari both work fine for me (and yes, they should render the same thing).

Comment: im using 9.0.597.84(chrome) on mac. which are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 8.0.552.237 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the issue the moment I updated Chrome on os x to the latest stable release (9.0.597.94) so this is a Chrome bug and hopefully will be fixed.

I'm tempted not to even attempt to work around this and just wait for the fix. It'll just mean more work taking it out.

Comment: mmm so it is confirmed then? is there a way to "downgrade" our chrome to check if it really is chrome?

Comment: it is 2013 and I still have this issue on the latest version of chrome: Version 27.0.1453.116 m

Answer (score 1):

The placeholder is not affected by `line-height` and `padding` is inconsistent on browsers.

I have found another solution though.

`VERTICAL-ALIGN`. This is probably the only time it works but try that instead and cave many lines of CSS code.

Comment: does not do anything for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer that remedied my frustrations regarding this on [John Catterfeld's blog](http://blog.ajcw.com/2013/09/css-placeholder-cross-browser-support/).

> ... Chrome (v20-30) implements almost all styles but with a major caveat – the placeholder styles do no resize the input box, so stay clear of things like line-height and padding top or bottom.

If you are using line-height or padding you are going to be frustrated with the resulting placeholder. I haven't found a way around that up to this point.