# HTML5, Placeholder, line-height in Webkit

Tags: html, css

I have an input field:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="whatever">
```

with styles:

```
input {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 6px;
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 19px;
    height: 36px;
    width: 255px;
}
```

Problem is the line-height is not taking effect for the placeholder in webkit CHROME. so the text in the input field is aligned in an ugly way. Anyone else seen this and now how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with placeholder?

Comment: The placeholder text in the input is not being aligned with the line-height CSS rule.

Comment: Looks like it's a Chrome bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919680/html5-placeholder-css-padding-problem

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looking at your tags, I'm assuming you are writing something like...

```
<input type="text" placeholder="whatever">
```

Unfortunately, Chrome ties your hands when it comes to styling the placeholder, the selector looks like this...

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {}
```

You can find the styling options, gotchas and supported browsers in [Styling the HTML Placeholder](http://blog.ajcw.com/2011/02/styling-the-html5-placeholder/)

Comment: Thanks for the help . however its unique. placeholder should inherit these styles implicitly.

Answer (score 27):

Input placeholders don't seem to like pixel line-height values, but this will vertically centre it in the input:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { line-height: normal; }
```

Comment: Please add some kind of clarification/explanation

Answer (score 10):

It appears that removing your line-height declaration entirely works. It's worked for me in FF7, Chrome15 and Safari 5.1. Also looked good in IE9 and FF3.6 but does NOT look good in IE8.

Comment: This worked for me. But in some cases you might not want to remove your `line-height` for inputs so it might not work for everyone.

Comment: Excellent. line-height:normal; is something I've never resorted to before but it makes sense here. I'd say placeholders and their fluctuating selector standards are a good excuse for some imperfect code that fixes it by removing rather than adding :)

Comment: The input element only operates on one line - line-height does not apply.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I can fully replicate your problem, but perhaps you can fix it using `padding: 7px 6px;`.
Doing this should hopefully set your top and bottom padding to 7px which pretty much does a similar job as `line-height`.  With different sizes (width/font-size) you should be able to choose the appropriate padding by calculating `(height - fontsize) / 2` perhaps give or take a pixel or two for perfection.