# iOS 5.0 Safari not vertically centering placeholder in text box

Tags: css, ios5, mobile-safari, vertical-alignment, placeholder

I want to vertically center the text entered in input text boxes on the page.

Typical way to achieve this is to set the line-height and height equal. This works on pre iOS 5.0 Safari.

However; on iOS 5, Safari displays the typed text vertically centered... But the placeholder text and the cursor appear top aligned.

```
.txtBox {
    line-height: 3em;
    height: 3em;
}
```

`<input type="text" class="txtBox" placeholder="Name"></input>`

Anyone else facing this issue?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919680/html5-placeholder-css-padding-problem

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Setting `line-height: 1;` seems to fix this.

Comment: how come this works... what is the logic behind this one? I am confused.

Comment: This cuts placeholders for Chrome and IE10. Downvoted!

Comment: This does not work across the board. See andychukse's answer below for a working solution.

Comment: See Marcel's answer for the correct solution. Do not use andychukse's answer, as that has problems as well.

Answer (score 40):

For me there is only one solution that appears close to perfect in all browsers I tested (Chrome, FF, Safari (+iOS), IE10):

`line-height: normal;`

Solutions like `line-height: 100%` and `line-height: 1;` seem to be aligned towards the top of the input, especially in Chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/5Vc3z/

Comparison:

http://jsfiddle.net/5Vc3z/1/

Comment: I agree with this. ```line-height: normal;``` is the only solution that worked in chrome for the placeholder. ```line-height: 1;``` had no effect.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I had issues with `line-height: 100%` and `line-height: 1;` in Chrome, and this is the only answer that worked for me.

Comment: yes, this should be correct answer. I've also tried `line-height` with `px`, but only this answer works

Comment: this should be the selected answer

Answer (score 7):

You should use percentage for the line-height.

```
.txtBox {
       line-height: 100%;
       height: 3em;
    }
<input type="text" class="txtBox" placeholder="Name"></input>
```

Comment: Works flawlessly. You can also use any percentage value, not only 100%. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This ought to be the accepted answer. For example, if we need to vertically center the text (by setting line-height equal to height), this renders that scenario correclty.

Comment: `line-height: normal;` is the better way to go, as shown in Marcel's answer. As he mentions in his answer, solutions like `line-height: 100%` and `line-height: 1;` seem to be aligned towards the top of the input, especially in Chrome.

Comment: `line-height: 100%` worked perfectly for me in old and new browsers alike

Answer (score 2):

<s>Assuming you are just trying to make the input field appear larger then you could use `padding`:</s>

```
.txtBox {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 1em auto;
}
```

Also, your input field should be:

```
<input type="text" class="txtBox" placeholder="Name" />
```

#### Edit

Sorry, took a little while. It appears that `placeholder` can be styled individually and / or inherit styles from the parent. Unfortunately there are quite a lot of styles that are not supported by Safari at this time.

The following blog has details about the styling techniques and which are / are not supported within certain browsers:

**http://blog.ajcw.com/2011/02/styling-the-html5-placeholder/**

Comment: Updated my question... actually its the placeholder text that is not appearing centered.

Answer (score 1):

I got stuck on this issue for a long time despite using

`input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
     line-height:normal!important;
}`

It turns out the having a line-height in the input element by itself was breaking my input::webkit-input-placeholder line-height.

**Solution extended:**

I removed the line-height in my input style and it fixed my issue.