# placeholder always align left in safari

Tags: html, css, safari

Placeholder text gets aligned left in safari browser. It is working good in all other browser.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-input" placeholder="Email Address" />
```

CSS:

```css
.form-input {
    width: 235px;
    height: 15px;    
    border: solid 5px #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px; 
    font-family: 'Helvetica-Bold';
}
```

Please see the demo in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sivaram2287/Gs5gU/54/)

I want to align the `placeholder` at center of the `input` box. How to do this?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7381446/2126792

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14986215/2126792 (also from another duplicate question).

Comment: Regarding the answers and comments in the other question threads, that seems to be an exclusive issue in Saf 5/5.1 on Windows 7, with no real solution apart from version-specific browser hacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it's working

CODE:

```
input { 
   text-align:center;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   text-align:center;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   text-align:center;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   text-align:center;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   text-align:center; 
}
```

will work in safari 6 as placeholder text-align property not working in safari 5.1 or older version

see support table here http://blog.ajcw.com/2011/02/styling-the-html5-placeholder/

Comment: input { text-align:center;} is not working in safari.It aligns the placeholder at left.

Comment: which version of safari on which os??

Comment: I am using safari 5.1.7 in windows 7 OS

Comment: See my answer safari 5.1.7 not supporting text-align for place holder , I have wrote above check my answer again ..

Comment: Any other hack way is there to make it work in safari 5.1 or older.

Comment: Nop. i dont think you can align placeholder... :/

Comment: This answer solve issue in safari version 6 < and my problem is not fixed completely.Can you give any clue to fix in safari 5.1 and lower.

Answer (score 1):

A more compact alternative and cross-browser way to do this (including much older browsers), is to use: `text-indent: Xpx;`.

Then you reset the `text-indent` to 0, on `input:focus` for the actual text.

Comment: Also those two references are useful in terms of which browser support what: [Making HTML5 input placeholder text behave in Safari](http://blog.omgmog.net/post/making-html5-input-placeholder-text-behave-in-safari/) and [Styling the HTML5 placeholder](http://blog.ajcw.com/2011/02/styling-the-html5-placeholder/)