# Align placeholder inside text field HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to move my placeholder in upper-left corner.

[image]

I want something like on the image.

I've tried

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    left: 0px;
    up: 0px;
}
```

But it doesn't work. I know HTML well, but I never did something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found answer by myself! :D

So, I just changed `<input>` to `<textarea>`. With a little CSS it looks completely same as input field.

Very much thanks for everyone who tried to help me!

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `text-align: center|left|right` to change the *align* of the input's *value/placeholder*.

*source:* https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/text-align

Otherwise you could use `padding: 0 0 0 0;` to force space

*source:* https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/padding

**Information**: *up* isn't valid css. the right name is *top*
And if you want to use position attributes like: `right, left, bottom` or `top` you have to set `position: absolute|fixed;`

Edit: As told in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5677243/3119231 it is possible to set `"top"` value through `line-height` attribute

Comment: Are we talking about a textarea or an input?

Comment: I want to align placeholder (text) that is inside input.

Comment: This is *impossible*. You can **align** it just **left, center** or **right**. But interesting question!

Answer (score 0):

I think css positioning can help. position relative or absolute. According to your container, try to give one of position styles.

EDIT: or you can use background-image instead of placeholder. and you can remove background image on mouse over with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you are limited to what styling can be applied to the `placeholder` pseudo-element.

[**Article**](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/styling-placeholder-text-input-fields-forms-css/)

These are:

- color
- font-size / font-style / font-weight
- letter-spacing
- line-height
- padding
- text-align
- text-decoration

Position is not one of them.

Comment: Not with the placeholder pseudo-element. You could try a positioned label instead.